# Trying to get a part of text data from a text file

Tags: python, string, dataframe, text

I am trying to clean some data for processing. My issue is the data is stored in the text file as follows:

```
{"cid": "UgxkXVjVOACj8XdC5B94AaABAg", "text": "اعملو كمان"}

{"cid": "UgyoMxW8lpPdIbk4qqp4AaABAg", "text": "#نطالب_بموسم_ثاني_من_سمعتوها_مني"}

{"cid": "Ugw3jFOC1rfRRGhi4QB4AaABAg", "text": "مالكم بطلتو تنزلو"}

{"cid": "Ugz3CzqPBYyJ0PEwjsd4AaABAg", "text": "1month ago\n28september2020"}
```

I am trying to work on the values the come after the "text": indicator but I don't know how to do it. I need the values stores in text to be in an array or a dataframe but the text file stores each line as an object and i don't know what to use to manipulate the file as this not Json nor dictionary.

Comment: looks like someone wrote a stringified dict to a file. Please find whomever gave you this file and tell them I'm crying

Comment: Use `ndjson` to read the parse string as newline-delimited json, then iterate over the list and get the `text` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html#pandas.read_json) with parameter `lines=True`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('file.txt', lines=True)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                          cid                              text
0  UgxkXVjVOACj8XdC5B94AaABAg                        اعملو كمان
1  UgyoMxW8lpPdIbk4qqp4AaABAg  #نطالب_بموسم_ثاني_من_سمعتوها_مني
2  Ugw3jFOC1rfRRGhi4QB4AaABAg                 مالكم بطلتو تنزلو
3  Ugz3CzqPBYyJ0PEwjsd4AaABAg       1month ago\n28september2020
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a list of those dictionaries in python using the following code:

```
import ast
data = [ast.literal_eval(i.strip()) for i in open("text.txt", "r+").readlines() if i != "\n"]

print(data)
```

output:

```
[{'cid': 'UgxkXVjVOACj8XdC5B94AaABAg', 'text': 'اعملو كمان'}, {'cid': 'UgyoMxW8lpPdIbk4qqp4AaABAg', 'text': '#نطالب_بموسم_ثاني_من_سمعتوها_مني'}, {'cid': 'Ugw3jFOC1rfRRGhi4QB4AaABAg', 'text': 'مالكم بطلتو تنزلو'}, {'cid': 'Ugz3CzqPBYyJ0PEwjsd4AaABAg', 'text': '1month ago\n28september2020'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick and easy way of doing it then I suggest regex

```
import re

data = #your input here

newtext = re.findall('"text": "(.*?)"}', data) #find all between the two parts in the data and store in a list
```